# Searching for @ followed by multiple characters in word document from Powershell

Tags: powershell, wildcard

I'm attempting to do a find replace on multiple word documents from Powershell. The string I'm looking to replace is in the format:

```
@XXXXXXX
```

with the X's being alphanumeric characters (this is what merge fields look like within our system).

The string I'm using as the text to find is:

```
"\@*"
```

Which I'm assuming to be anything starting with an @ followed by multiple characters. The backslash acts as the escape character for the wildcard @ within Word.

This is only replacing the @ signs within the document though, and ignoring the characters after it.

How can I set the search term to respect the @ and the characters after it and replace them all?

The full script in it's current form is:

```
$list = Get-ChildItem "H:\Quick Report Replace" -Include *.xml -recurse

$objWord = New-Object -ComObject word.application
$objWord.Visible = $False

foreach ($foo in $list) {

$objDoc = $objWord.Documents.Open("$foo")
$objSelection = $objDoc.Selection

$findtext= "\@*"
$ReplaceText = "_______________"

$ReplaceAll = 2
$FindContinue = 1
$MatchFuzzy = $False
$MatchCase = $False
$MatchPhrase = $false
$MatchWholeWord = $False
$MatchWildcards = $True
$MatchSoundsLike = $False
$MatchAllWordForms = $False
$Forward = $True
$Wrap = $FindContinue
$Format = $False

$objSelection.Find.execute(
        $FindText,
        $MatchCase,
        $MatchWholeWord,
        $MatchWildcards,
        $MatchSoundsLike,
        $MatchAllWordForms,
        $Forward,
        $Wrap,
        $Format,
        $ReplaceText,
        $ReplaceAll
    )

If ($objSelection.Find.Found) 
{ 
    Write-Host("The search text was found.") } Else { 
    Write-Host("The search text was not found.") } 

$objDoc.close()

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Word does non-greedy matches, so your expresssion `\@*` will only match the *shortest* number of characters after a literal `@`. Since there's nothing after the `*` wildcard that would act as an anchor the shortest number of characters in your case is always zero, so you'll only ever match the `@` character itself.

To match subsequent alphanumeric characters as well you need to anchor the end of the expression somewhere, for instance at a word boundary:

```
\@*>
```

Comment: That's worked great, thank you. Now I just need to work out how to ignore email addresses!